# Can't stop correct function JS

Tags: javascript, onclick, chat, break

I have game with chat panel, and I have two functions to send and repeat my messages.

I want to stop my reapeat function on click "stop" button. I made someting like this, but in this way I crashed all my game session. Where I'm doing a mistake?

```
$("#start-spam").click(function () {

    var numberOfMessages = 9999; //$("#spambot-wiadomosci").val();

    var messagesSendingSpeed = 1; //$("#spambot-szybkosc").val();

    var messageToSend = $("#spam-input").val();

    var numberOfSendedMessages = 0;

    function sendMessage(messageToSend) {
    document.getElementById("chat_textbox").value = messageToSend;
    var e = new Event("keydown");
    e.key = 13;
    e.keyCode = 13;
    e.wich = 13;
    window.dispatchEvent(e);
    window.dispatchEvent(e);
};

function repeatMessage(messageToSend, numberOfMessages, messagesSendingSpeed) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        sendMessage(messageToSend);
        numberOfSendedMessages++;
        if(numberOfSendedMessages < numberOfMessages) {
            repeatMessage(messageToSend, numberOfMessages, messagesSendingSpeed);
        }
    }, messagesSendingSpeed);

    if($("#stop-spam").click()){
        return true;
    }
};
repeatMessage(messageToSend, numberOfMessages, messagesSendingSpeed);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call the [`.click()`][1] method without arguments, it returns a jQuery object.

If you want to associate an action to the click event, you must pass a function as argument

```js
$("#stop-spam").click(function() {
  console.log('clicked on the button');
  // more code
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="stop-spam">stop</button>
```

To stop your action, there are many ways your logic could be improved, but from the current state, the easiest might be to use a boolean to check whether or not to execute the function again.

```
var keepGoing = true;

function repeatMessage(messageToSend, numberOfMessages, messagesSendingSpeed) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        sendMessage(messageToSend);
        numberOfSendedMessages++;
        if (keepGoing ) {
            if (numberOfSendedMessages < numberOfMessages) {
                repeatMessage(messageToSend, numberOfMessages, messagesSendingSpeed);
            }
        }
    }, messagesSendingSpeed);
};


$("#stop-spam").click(function() {
  console.log('clicked on the button');
  keepGoing = false;
});
```

Comment: Ok, but i want to stop the repeatMessage function on click button Stop.

Comment: Then you have to store the return value from the setTimeout function and call ```cancelTimeout(returnValu)``` to cancel it.

Comment: It is called clearTimeout and not cancel. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Answer (score 0):

There is alot of wierdness in there.

1. Break out the 2 functions so that you dont create them on click.
2. To stop somrthing on a click even you have to add a click event with a handler, similar to what you did on top. Not call it with `if ($('something').click())` which instead triggers click on that element.
3. You are not spamming since set timeout only runs once. You might be looking for `setInterval`? In which case you use the `clearInterval` to stop it.

Comment: Well. Javascript uses function scoping so any variables declared inside the function that created the event handler or globally will be accessable inside your function.